# How to default a ion-toggle to on?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using an [`ion-toggle`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/) in Ionic 2, that I would like to default to on. I have tried the `checked` attribute, but it still defaults to off.

`<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="ratingModel.contact" formControlName="contact" id="contact" checked="true">Contactable</ion-toggle>`

How do I default a `ion-toggle` to true or on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Component code, set the `ratingModel.contact` property to true:

`ratingModel.contact = true;`